# pygame is not working

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to play a song with pygame and it is not playing the song.

*My code:*

```
import pygame,time
pygame.init()
print "Mixer settings", pygame.mixer.get_init()
print "Mixer channels", pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(1.0)
pygame.mixer.music.load('C:/1.mp3')
print "Play"
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
   print "Playing", pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()
time.sleep(1)
print "Done"
```

*I am getting output as*

```
Mixer settings (22050, -16, 2)
Mixer channels 8
Play
Done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me, on Lubuntu 11.10 running Python 2.7.2, with an MP3 I converted from a Youtube clip. Have you checked that the mp3 is not zero length? Have you tried a wav file?

Lacking other explanations, I think it is conceivable that `pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()` could be returning false if the `play(0)` call hasn't finished starting its process or thread.
This would cause your code to skip the while loop, print "Done", and terminate, deleting the music player object and terminating playback before you got to hear anything. If this is the problem, you could try something like this after `play(0)` and before `print Done`:

```
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(pygame.USEREVENT)
finishedPlaying = False

while not finishedPlaying:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT: 
            finishedPlaying = True
            break # only because we don't care about any other events
    print "Playing", pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() # will print -1 on the last iteration
```

Answer (score 0):

in the comments of pygame.mixer.music.play i found this:

```
November 18, 2010 7:30pm - Anonymous
Work Exmpl:

pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=4096)
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('Time_to_coffee.wav').play()
```

also it seems that your sending 0 as the amount of times you want to repeat it **thanks  Iskar Jarak** , -1 is infinity.

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried this. But, it is still not playing the song.

Comment: "Be aware that MP3 support is limited. On some systems an unsupported format can crash the program, e.g. Debian Linux. Consider using OGG instead."

Comment: "also it seems that your sending 0 as the amount of times you want to play it, -1 is infinity." This is incorrect - the argument is the number of times to repeat it. 0 should play the song once.